# HtmlAgilityPack retrieve innerText without children's Innertext

Tags: html-agility-pack

I have

```
<p class="MyClass">
<span>Value:</span>
12345
</p>
```

I'd like to retrieve only `12345`, if possible, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the most elegant solution, but what about

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;
using ScrapySharp.Extensions;
using System.Linq;
using HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelectors.NetCore;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(@"<p class='MyClass'>
                           <span>Value:</span>
                            12345
                        </p>");

            //Using ScrapySharp.Extensions
            var p = doc.DocumentNode.CssSelect("p")?.FirstOrDefault();
            var span = p.CssSelect("span")?.FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine(p.InnerText.Replace(span.InnerHtml, string.Empty)?.Trim());

            //Using HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelectors.NetCore
            var results = doc.QuerySelectorAll("p")?.Select(p => p.InnerText.Replace(p.QuerySelector("span").InnerHtml, string.Empty)?.Trim());
            foreach(var result in results)
                Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S.**: I am used to working with ScrapySharp in conjunction to HtmlAgilityPack, but see that there is a HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelectors.NetCore that may the common choice nowadays.